# Assigning a numerical value to day and time

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a column in df that contains numerical values that correlate to the customers hour of week for that row. For example **0 = Sunday 12:00am** and **24 would be Monday 12:00am** and **5 would be Sunday 5:00am**.

```
  Value 
    0
    4
    10
    24

  Value  Expected Output Column
    0           Sunday 12:00am
    4           Sunday 4:00am
    10          Sunday 10:00am
    24          Monday 12:00am
    49          Tuesday 1:00am
```

How can I create the new column if I want all values to assign to a correct corresponding Day and time for the week? Values start at 0 which would represent Sunday 12:00am first value of week and would end at 167 which would be Saturday 11:59pm of that week.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This does what you want:

```
Value = pd.Series([0, 4, 10, 24, 49])
AnyGivenSunday = pd.to_datetime('Sunday 2020') # yes this works
(AnyGivenSunday + pd.to_timedelta(Value, 'h')).dt.strftime('%A %I:%M%P')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
import calendar as cal

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'val': [0, 0, 0, 0, 0], 'date': ["Sunday 12:00am", "Sunday 4:00am", "Sunday 10:00am", "Monday 12:00am", "Tuesday 1:00am"]})

def convertDate(dateString):
    hour = datetime.strptime(dateString, '%A %I:%M%p').hour # Convert to 24 hour format
    day, time = dateString.split(" ") # Get text of day, cannot get datetime.weekday() without full date
    if day.lower() == cal.day_name[6].lower(): # cal.day_name index starts at Monday and not Sunday
        return hour + ((list(cal.day_name).index(day) - 6) * 24)
    else:
        return hour + ((list(cal.day_name).index(day) + 1) * 24)

df['val'] = df['date'].apply(convertDate) # Apply function to all columns
```